# MYSQL query that orders data by timestamps contained in two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a query that will order results by date and time, but the date and time upon which I want to base the ordering is contained in two tables. Additionally,  I'd like to group the data by loc_id for rows having the same date.

For example, if I had this data:

[image]

Notes:
- parent_id links to the id in TABLE A. 
- there are two other tables USER and LOC which are used to get the user name and location name. 
- comments are optional in TABLE A, but will always exist in TABLE B.

I've found a lot of info on this site that's close to what I need, but nothing that's quite helped me solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.`date`
     , a.`time`
     , l.loc_name AS l_name
     , a.rating
     , a.comment
     , u.user_name
FROM table_a AS a
  LEFT JOIN loc AS l 
    ON l.loc_id = a.loc_id
  LEFT JOIN `user` AS u
    ON u.user_id = a.user_id

UNION ALL

SELECT b.`date`
     , b.`time`
     , l.loc_name AS l_name
     , NULL AS rating
     , b.comment
     , u.user_name
FROM table_b AS b
  LEFT JOIN table_a AS a
    ON a.id = b.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN loc AS l 
    ON l.loc_id = a.loc_id
  LEFT JOIN `user` AS u
    ON u.user_id = b.user_id

ORDER BY `date`
       , l_name
       , `time`
```

Comment: I think this will do what I need, but I'm getting an error on the loc_id in the ORDER BY clause: MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'loc_id' in 'order clause'

Comment: I added one more entry to each SELECT: , a.loc_id.  Now it works!  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, change it to `loc_name`. If you need to order by `loc_id` there, it will be only a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited your answer so everyone can see what I did, but I don't think you'll see the changes until it's been peer reviewed.  It does exactly what I asked for so thanks!  One more question if you don't mind. Would it be easy to add a WHERE clause so that I could run the query on a specific location?  (something like WHERE l.loc_id = 26, for example)?

Comment: @user418775: yes, just add `WHERE l.loc_id = 26` to **both** subqueries.

Comment: And a note: This kind on `UNION` and then `ORDER BY` can result in a very slow query if your tables are just a bit more than small.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

(Assumed your users table was called **users** and your locations table **locations**.)

```
SELECT a.date, a.time, l.loc_name, a.rating, b.comment, u.user_name
FROM table_a a
JOIN locations l ON l.loc_id = a.loc_id
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.parent_id = a.id
RIGHT JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id

GROUP BY a.loc_id

ORDER BY a.date DESC, a.time DESC
```

Comment: I've been trying this solution, but I get an error on the GROUP BY: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY a.loc_id.  If I remove ORDER BY I don't get the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the Group By should be placed ABOVE the Order By. My bad.. -.-

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I placed GROUP BY above and the query run now, but it only returns data from table_a.  The other answer provides what I need.  Cheers.

Comment: @Jules: Actually, `GROUP BY` is not needed, despite the OP's description (`I'd like to group the data by loc_id`). He means to **order by** date, then loc_id, then time (as the result set shows).

Comment: @ypercube: Mmmh, then I misinterpreted his question.. :(